# Form inside a PHP echo won't POST any data

Tags: php, html, echo

I have a form inside php which only displays when a user is logged in, this means that only logged in users can make a new blogpost on my site, the form looks like this:

```
<?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){ ?>

        <section class="post">
            <h3>Make a new post:</h3>
            <p> Before posting anything, make sure you have read the <a id="pagelink" href="rules.html"> rules </a>
            <form action="../php/post_up.php" id="newpost" method="POST">
                <table id="post">
                    <tr>
                        <td> Title: </td>
                        <td id="post_cell"> <input type="text" name="post_title"/> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td> Content: </td>
                        <td id="post_cell"> <textarea name="post_content" form="newpost" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="submit" name="submit_post" value="Submit">
                        </td>
                    <tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </section>
        <?php
            }

            require("../php/load_up.php");
        ?>
```

After this the code is sent to this php script:

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once("../php/db.php");

if(!isset($_SESSION['userid'])){
    header("Location: ../blog/userpost.php");
    die();
}

if(isset($_POST['submit_post'])){
    if(isset($_POST['post_title']) && isset($POST['post_content'])){
        if(!$_POST['post_title'] == "" && !$_POST['post_content'] == ""){

            $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];

            $title = strip_tags($_POST['post_title']);
            $content = strip_tags($_POST['post_content']);

            $title = stripslashes($title);
            $content = stripslashes($content);

            $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($title);
            $content = mysqli_real_escape_string($content);

            $sql_store_post = "INSERT INTO userpost (title,content,userid) VALUES ('$title','$content','$userid')";

            mysqli_query($db, $sql_store_post);

            header("Location: ../blog/userpost.php");
            die();

        } else {
            echo("The posts are empty");    
        }
    } else {
        echo("The posts are not set");  
    }
} 

elseif(isset($_POST['submit_comment'])){

}

else {
    echo("Seems like submit has not been set?");
    //header("Location: ../blog/userpost.php"); 
}
```

?>

The weird thing is that `isset($_POST['submit_post'])` returns true, however the two following posts both return false, resulting in errors in my code.

PS: The `require("../php/load_up.php");` is only to display the posts that have already been made and is not important in the process of posting the data.

Comment: can you `var_dump($_POST)` ?

Comment: Instead of `!$_POST['post_title'] == ""` use `!empty(trim($_POST['post_title']))`.

Comment: btw, when you compare strings, you need to use [strcmp()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strcmp.php)

Comment: ^ notice the weird returns when using `strcmp` otherwise you'll be stuck.

Comment: As well as the typo @Script47 highlighted, `mysqli_real_escape_string` takes two parameters

Comment: @Steve Just a note that I didn't rely on your comment about the answer I submitted, I didn't see it. I'm not like that and it's not my style.

Comment: @Fred-ii- No need for the note - i know you put in more effort than i do trying to educate the uneducatable here in the php tag!

Comment: @Steve Cheers Steve. However, I felt I did have to post that. Others who don't know me as you do, might think othewise.

Answer (score 2):

Besides your typo for `$POST['post_content']` for the [POST superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) which should read as `$_POST['post_content']` with the underscore between the `$` and `POST`:

This piece of code:

```
$title = mysqli_real_escape_string($title);
$content = mysqli_real_escape_string($content);
```

[`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) requires a database connnection

```
$title = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $title);
$content = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $content);
```

In not doing so, you will be thrown something similar to this:

> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in (path to file) on line x

Plus, make sure the session was started inside all pages using sessions. You haven't shown that in your first body of code.

You should also check for errors against your query.

By adding `or die(mysqli_error($db))` to `mysqli_query()`.

Error reporting would have thrown you an undefined variable $ notice:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

and the missing db parameter for your escape function would have thrown you another error:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Modify:

```
mysqli_query($db, $sql_store_post);
```

to:

```
$query = mysqli_query($db, $sql_store_post);

if($query){
   echo "Success";
}

else{
   echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($db));
}
```

to check if the query was successful or not.

---

It's unclear what's inside `require_once("../php/db.php");`

Make sure that you are indeed successfully connected to your database and using the same MySQL API as your query.

- Different APIs do not intermix.

---

Sidenote:

These statements,

```
if(isset($_POST['post_title']) && isset($_POST['post_content'])){
        if(!$_POST['post_title'] == "" && !$_POST['post_content'] == ""){
```

can be narrowed down to simply:

```
if(!empty($_POST['post_title']) && !empty($_POST['post_content']))
```

and getting rid of `if(!$_POST['post_title'] == "" && !$_POST['post_content'] == ""){`

and its related closing `}` brace.

Answer (score 1):

A simple typo,

```
isset($POST['post_content'])){
```

to,

```
isset($_POST['post_content'])){
```